# HTTP Digest Authentication using asiHttpRequest

Tags: safari

I am trying to use asiHttpRequest to handle HTTP Digest Authentication, I have two textfields, one is name and the other is password, when the user login with the correct name and password a label will display the auth and userid response string. Can anyone provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code of how u can sent request to google for authentication. You can change it for digestion. Hope it helps.

```
    NSString *username = @"my.google.login@gmail.com";
    NSString *password = @"mypassword123";
    NSString *loginUrl = @"https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin?client=NNW-Mac";
    NSString *source = @"NNW-Mac"; //let's fake NetNewsWire
    NSString *continueUrl = @"http://www.google.com";

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: loginUrl]]; // log in & get cookies
    [request addRequestHeader: @"User-Agent" value: @"NetNewsWire/3.2b25 (Mac OS X; http://www.newsgator.com/Individuals/NetNewsWire/)"];

    [request setPostValue: username forKey: @"Email"];
    [request setPostValue: password forKey: @"Passwd"];
    [request setPostValue: @"reader" forKey: @"service"];
    [request setPostValue: source forKey: @"source"];
    [request setPostValue: continueUrl forKey: @"continue"];

    [request setDelegate: self];
    [request setDidFailSelector: @selector(loginRequestFailed:)];
    [request setDidFinishSelector: @selector(loginRequestFinished:)];

    [request start];
```

**Edit 1:**

```
            NSString *username = @"Login info";
            NSString *password = @"Password";
            NSString *loginUrl = @"http://connect.twangoo.com";
            NSString *continueUrl = @"http://www.google.com";

            ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: loginUrl]]; // log in & get cookies
    //Dont need it if u dont want to add any header value for the site
    //[request addRequestHeader: @"User-Agent" value: @"NetNewsWire/3.2b25 (Mac OS X; http://www.newsgator.com/Individuals/NetNewsWire/)"];

            [request setPostValue: username forKey: @"Login"];
            [request setPostValue: password forKey: @"Pwd"];

//Just for google api reader service u dont need it here..
//[request setPostValue: @"reader" forKey: @"service"];

            [request setDelegate: self];
            [request setDidFailSelector: @selector(loginRequestFailed:)];
            [request setDidFinishSelector: @selector(loginRequestFinished:)];

            [request start];
```

Comment: can u explain how to change it? Thanks

Comment: see above edit for direct digest authentication. Its the simplest one. I have not authenticated with twangoo.com before.. sorry cant be of more help.